# Is it possible to bind inner Div Click to Outer Div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to trigger a Function whenever I click on a Div, but that Div has an inner Div which means that If I click inside it it will trigger the onClick but on the wrong Div

I've looked around on Internet but couldn't find any answers.

A map function that returns the code below

```
<Card onClick={props.setSelectedTemplate}  key={template.id} className="AdCopies" id={template.id.toString()}>
        <SimpleAdCopy headlines={template.headlines} descriptions={template.descriptions} url={'www.google.com'}/>
 </Card>

function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id)
  }
```

I need the click to be always bounded to the outer div even if I click on the inner Div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). `target` is what was clicked, `currentTarget` is the element the event was bound to.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood it is about the React, isn't it?
Anyway if you want to stop event bubbling (https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) you should add onClick handler to the inner div and inside a callback do something like this

```
<SimpleAdCopy onClick= {event => event.stopPropagation()} />
```

It stops event bubbling and lets you avoid onClick invocation on outer div

About stop propagation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: "I need the click to be always bounded to the outer div even if I click on the inner Div" How does your answer help that?

Comment: Bounded to outer div as HTML element? in this case, you could only find outer div into onclick handler and do something with it.